Treating memory region atomically in Rust
Imagine we have an access to continuous memory region with an alignment of 8 and size of the region being a multiple of 8.
Now, let's say I want to use a particular segment of that region, but I want an exclusive access to it, so I use first 8 bytes of that region to set a "busy" flag along with the length of the segment that I'm using.
The problem is that I need to set and subsequently clear this flag (after I'm done with using it) in an atomic fashion to avoid race conditions, if multiple threads periodically allocate some memory from the same region.
Using a bit of unsafe we can transmute those initial 8 bytes into AtomicUsize (assuming 64 bit processor) and then use atomic load/store/CAS operations on it, which should solve the problem with parallel access, at least in theory.
Now the question, would I be violating some compiler invariants and introduce UB with such an approach, or is it a completely sound thing to do?
Assumptions: segment "allocations" always happen at properly (8 byte) aligned addresses, initial 8 bytes are never accidentally overwritten or treated in non-atomic fashion.

So you want to use the first 8 bytes of a chunk of shared memory as a lock.  A mutex, a semaphore.  Usually you don't need to roll your own with atomic ops; I'm assuming Rust has some standard-library mutex you can use. If you need a try_lock function that simply returns false instead of blocking (so you can try to grab ownership of a different chunk now instead of waiting for the other thread to finish using the chunk), look for a lock with that functionality.  So perhaps a simple spinlock.

If you never need to block, rolling your own is fine, just acquire exchange a 1 into it to take the lock (if you read the old value as 0), release store 0 to unlock.  No need to use all 64 bits, 32 is plenty.

@PeterCordes thanks for the reply, this is mostly an educational foray into the dark arts of Rust :D. So the idea is to implement the whole thing as a lock-free DS, hence I want to roll up my own implementation. As for the 64 bits, the storage is not just for the "taken" flag, but also for the length of used segment, besides 64 bit Atomics perform better on x64 processors as they are the size of machine word, and thus more preferable unless memory constraints are of an issue.

besides 64 bit Atomics perform better on x64 processors as they are the size of machine word,  The most efficient operand-size on x86-64 is 32-bit.  It's equal in most ways for things other than division, but 32-bit saves a bit of machine-code size (no REX prefix needed for instructions that don't use R8-R15).  The advantages of using 32bit registers/instructions in x86-64 . x86-64 caches even support writes as narrow as 1 byte with no penalty (unlike AArch64).  But if you have other useful stuff to store there, then sure.

Using atomic operations doesn't make your algorithm lock-free if you implement a lock.  Conversely, your algorithm can still be lock-free using a library spinlock but only ever calling try_lock and unlock, and being able to make forward progress by looking for a different chunk if try_lock failed.  But again, if you want to use the low bit of the size for this, you would need to roll your own.  A library spinlock would want at least a byte to itself.

Unlock can still be a single release-store (not RMW) if you keep around the original length value you read with its low bit being 0.  Actually, since you own the lock, a non-atomic RMW of load(relaxed) / clear the low bit / store(release) is fine.

Thanks for clarifications @PeterCordes, didn't know about code 32 bit optimization. As for "lock-free"ness, the will not be a spin lock or anything, if the CAS fails to set the "taken" bit then the allocation simply fails, no need to wait for anything. Or we can just jump to the next segment using length stored in the atomic and try to lock that, anyway that's a bit irrelevant to the question.

The question is quite too abstract. Do you want to transmute &mut u64 to &mut AtomicU64, or &u64 to &AtomicU64, or something else?

You probably want fetch_or rather than CAS, so you don't have to read first to create an "expected" pattern for CAS.  (But a failed CAS on some non-x86 ISAs might avoid getting the cache line into MESI Exclusive state, but even just reading it will mean the other thread (which is going to unlock it soon) loses exclusive/modified state so will at least need to send out an invalidate, if not a read-for-ownership. On x86, lock cmpxchg always dirties the cache line.)

On x86, a sufficiently-clever compiler can compile 1 & x.fetch_or(1) into lock bts.  But that doesn't also give you the length.  If you use the full return value from fetch_or, then yeah a compiler would have to implement fetch_or with a lock cmpxchg retry loop anyway, so you might as well use CAS manually.  And I guess test the locked bit in the value you read before doing a CAS.  Only lock xadd can do math and read the old value.  So that could work if you use the top bit instead of bottom, but creating a u64 1<<63 constant in a register is slightly more expensive than 1.

@ChayimFriedman the question is about transmuting memory region referenced by a pointer into a pointer to AtomicX and then operate on it.
The memory region is properly aligned sequence of u8s (obviously), and the intention is to take some chunk of that region and operate on it in atomic fashion, so if I have *const u8, I wont to turn it into *const AtomicX, and then perform various bit manipulation on it.

@PeterCordes appreciate the tips on lower level insights into atomic instructions

This touches some subtle parts of the memory model.
First of all arises the question of whether there will be both atomic and non-atomic reads/writes to the memory region at the same time. Mixed atomic and non-atomic reads (which are UB in C++) were just defined to not be UB in Rust. However, when any of them is a write (either the atomic or the non-atomic), this becomes UB. So you have to ensure all accesses are atomic.
Then there is the question of how exactly you obtained the pointer. If you have a mutable reference to the region (&mut [u8] or something alike), you are allowed to convert this into &mut Atomic (and there is even safe, although unstable, API for that). But then, no other reference is allowed to be used to access this region (because of the mutable reference).
If you have a shared reference (&[u8]), the story becomes more complicated. Under Stacked Borrows, it is immediate Undefined Behavior to transmute a shared reference to a reference to UnsafeCell (which atomics contain). Tree Borrows, on the other hand, allow this, but it does not allow writes into this UnsafeCell, only reads. This is even what of the very few parts of the memory model that is final in some way, because LLVM's noalias mandates this, at least for shared references that are function parameters (and therefore, it may be possible to trigger an actual miscompilation with this).
If you have a raw pointer that was never a reference (e.g. all usages of the region use this pointer, then it doesn't matter if previously it was a mutable reference), then it is fine to transmute it to a &Atomic (not &mut Atomic!), as long as you make sure no references are created for the non-atomic type.

Thank you for a detailed explanation. Regarding mixed atomic and non atomic read/writes, imagine the following scenario:

We have a static memory region, which we create at some point by Box leaking a Vec<u8> and obtain a *mut u8 to it.
Only one thread exclusively holds that pointer
When someone requests an allocation, we check a guard area, which is 4 bytes long.
Before performing read, we cast it into *const Atomicu32




If taken bit is unset, we set it and then send out this *const Atomic32 to another thread, and guarantee that nothing will touch those 4 bytes except the owner of *const Atomicu32, and owner will only access it via atomic operations.


Once the taken bit is unset (and we check it via atomic load), we guarantee that no references to the area exist via *const Atomicu32


At this point, can we reuse the area for writes non-atomically?

@BaburMakhmudov Assuming you establish a happens-before relationship, yes. Mixed atomic access is only about concurrent access (or access without happens-before which is the same as concurrent access).
